# how to specify a div's position as absolute and relative at the same time

Tags: css

I'm new here and I want to know how to specify a div's position as absolute and relative at the same time, Because a div can be a child and parent simultaneously . 
Thank you for your help

Comment: You're question is unclear - why would you need such a behavior? Anyway, position is a CSS property, and thus can only have one value at a time.

Comment: Quite obviously, this is impossible. But maybe if you have a design/sample code of what you are looking to do, then the community may be able to help you achieve it without "specify a div's position as absolute and relative at the same time"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If the child is positioned absolutely, any **grandchild** can be again positioned absolutely *in relation* to the child.

That is, the child does not need to have `position:relative` for the grandchild to be positioned absolutely *in relation* to it.

So the child could be *considered* to have `position:absolute` for it's own positioning but also "relative" as it also **forms the reference point** for the positioning of the grandchild.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="g-child"></div>
  </div>
</div>

.parent {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  margin: 1em auto;
 position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  background: orange;
}

.g-child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #f00;
  top:125%;
  right: 0;
}
```

[**Codepen demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ZpZNpV)

Comment: Thanks  a lot man , I was confused for a long time by this . (y)

Comment: Nice - out of curiosity, how would you make the grandchild position relative to the parent in your example?

Answer (score 0):

If you require some benefit of absolute positioning (to escape an ancestors overflow for example) but also take up space in the page flow, one trick I use is to duplicate the content inline but then set 'visibility: hidden;' on the inline content so only the absolute item is visible.

Comment: Consider that duplicating content will make updating the content much harder in the future.

Do leave an example in code and/or propose a different solution if you can.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to position an HTML block.
If you position it as `fixed` then it will ignore other blocks and position itself in the browser window.
If you position it as `static` (or don't position it at all, 'cause that is the default) then it will move along the flow of the page.
If you position it as `relative`, then you're moving it from its "normal" place (according to the page's flow).
If you position it as `absolute`, then you're positioning it relative to its closest ancestor which is `fixed` or `relative`...

Clearly, nothing can be `absolute` and `relative` at the same time. Either you want the element to position itself based on another ancestor's position or based on the page flow. I fail to see how it can be both.

Comment: Well, it seems to me Paulie_D assumed you wanted different elements to be relative and absolute, which is not what I would call "at the same time", so I suppose we just have different definitions for that expression. That said, I see no reason why you should be sarcastic with me for trying to answer your question honestly... Rest assured I will remember your name and never try to help (or rather bother, apparently) you ever again. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: what ?, I wasn't sarcastic at all , All I said is I'm thankful for your answer , but Paulie_D did understand what I want to mean even if my question is a litle bit unclear . Thnx anyway and really sorry for any misunderstanding

Comment: Unless you want it to be relative on the Y axis and absolute on the X axis.